# Css doesn't Work on Iphone

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hLza6qa6/3/

when i test my fiddle on iPhone menu links on overlay does not appear but when i test it on android device , it's all Ok .

```
 .menu-links{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: medium none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        opacity: 0;
        padding-right: 7px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 300ms ease-out 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0s;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 800;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Any advice would be great ? Thanks

Comment: i think the position: absolute; make them invisible but without this menu is not what i want

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `-webkit-transform` below each `transform` property.

According to the [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), transform is supported with -webkit- on Safari